# Return type out-of-line definition differs from that in the declaration

Tags: c++

First time asking so be gentle.

I am having a problem with a returning a custom type for a function. To be more specific, I have a linked list, and I am writing a function that traverses to the end of the list and returns a pointer to that node. Unfortunately, I am getting a pesky error:

"Return type out-of-line definition of mySpace::CDAL::tailNode differs from that in the declaration"

The header file contains within the "mySpace" namespace and the template class CDAL

```
private:

struct Node
{....};
```

the function header

```
Node* tailNode();
```

and in the .cpp

```
template <typename T>
struct Node* mySpace::CDAL<T>::tailNode()
{...}
```

I tried using struct because someone had mentioned for non-typedef declarations you sometimes would need it, and I no longer received the unknown type error, but received this instead.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: In addition to my answer, you shouldn't define templates inside a .cpp file unless you really know what you're doing. They will give undefined references when using them. Instead simply define the function inside the .h file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Node` is declared within `mySpace::CDAL<T>` so its name has to be qualified in the definition:

```
template <typename T>
struct typename mySpace::CDAL<T>::Node* mySpace::CDAL<T>::tailNode()
{...}
```

`struct` also isn't needed. Taking it out won't make a difference.